# Checking with meteor if browser FF and replacing input type="date" with JQuery datapicker

Tags: jquery, meteor, meteor-blaze

Html5 *input type="date"* doesn't work with Firefox. How can replace it for Firefox with this simple https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ datapicker? This should work with my blaze-template:

**html**

```
<template name="myTemplate">
{{#each showDates}}
 <li>
  <input id="datepicker" type="date" value={{date}}" />
 </li>
{{each}}
</template>
```

**js** (updated #1)

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){
  //replacing html5-date with jquery for FF doesn't work?
  if(BrowserDetect.browser == "Firefox"){
    alert("FIREFOX USER!");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
  }
});
```

I get following error:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: TypeError:
>
> $(...).datepicker is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
 meteor add awatson1978:browser-detection
```

check  https://atmospherejs.com/awatson1978/browser-detection

Comment: Detection works, but I can't replace it with JQuery. I have updated my code after your answer. I get "$(...).datepicker is not a function" error.